# How to use IF to plot the valuers higher than x

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have an Excell file and I want to plot all values higher than **200000** (for example) in the column **Verkaufspreis**

```
#Calling the Excell file
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("wohnungspreise.xlsx")



#ploting the date in a table
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(df["Quadratmeter"], df["Verkaufspreis"])
if(df["Verkaufspreis"] > 200000){
    plt.show()
}
```

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` of `jupyter-lab` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: You can not use `{` and `}` to create blocks in Python. Python strictly uses code indentation (the white spaces at the line start) to know which block belong together. [Official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming)

Comment: You can try `plt.scatter(df[df["Verkaufspreis"] > 200000]["Quadratmeter"], df[df["Verkaufspreis"] > 200000]["Verkaufspreis"])` to only plot the values higher than 200000.